# Query Python3 script to get stats about the script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that continually runs and accepts data (For those that are familiar and if it helps, it is connected to EMDR - https://eve-market-data-relay.readthedocs.org).

Inside the script I have debugging built in so that I can see how much data is currently in the queue for the threads to process, however this is built to be used with just printing to the console. What I would like to do is be able to either run the same script with an additional option or a totally different script that would return the current queue count without having to enable debug.

Is there a way to do this could someone please point me in the direction of the documentation/libaries that I need to research?

Comment: So do you want to be able to query the script while it's running, and to get a count of the items queued in memory? If so, you could check out https://github.com/google/pyringe. 

The other options would probably involve modifying the script so that it either periodically broadcasts the information you're interested in, or persists it to some storage (e.g., a file) that you can access externally.

Comment: @JomelImperio, Thanks for the github link. it does look interesting but does not work with Python3. It is looking like I will need to just write to a log file or write a counter that sends an email at a certain count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this; two that come to mind:

1. You can write the queue count to a k/v store (like memcache or redis) and then have another script read that for you and do whatever other actions required.
2. You can create a specific logger for your informational output (like the queue length) and set it to log somewhere else other than the console. For example, you could use it to send you an email or log to an external service, etc. See the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html) for examples.

Comment: I completely forgot about the logger, I think I will either just do some testing and see what count would be considered overload on my script and then probably incorporate both an email and file log.

Also thank you for pointing me at redis, it looks like it could be fun to incorporate as well.